# Vue.js show answer after submit

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I need to display the answer in the answer block. {correctanswer(question.responses)}} currently I am getting undfiened as I loop through the responses

```
<div class="ques_block" v-for="(question, index) in quiz.questions">

    <div v-show="index === questionIndex">
        <h3>{{index + 1}}) {{question.text}}</h3>
            <div class="option_div" v-for="(response,resp) in question.responses">
                <input type="radio" v-bind:name="index"  v-bind:value="response.correct"  v-model="userResponses[index]"/>
                <label>   {{response.text}} </label>
            </div>
            <!--<div class="frm_grp">
                <a href="" v-on:click.prevent="submit" class="submit_answer" >Submit</a>
            </div>-->
            <div class="error_block hide alert alert-success">  
                <p>Correct</p>
            </div>
            <div class="error_block hide alert alert-danger">   
                <p>Incorrect</p>
            </div>
            <div class="answer_block ">
                <h4>Answer Details</h4>
                <p>Option {{correctanswer(question.responses)}} is the correct answer</p>
            </div>
```

This function is not working it says response is undefined.

```
        correctanswer: function (responses) {
            var mapping = ["A", "B", "C" , "D", "E"];
            var $i = 0;

            for(var response in responses){
                console.log(response.correct);
                if(response.correct) {
                    break;
                }
                $i++;
            }

            return mapping[$i+1];
          },
```

[jsfiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/Bl_praveen2004/7Lm69peh/1/)

Comment: If you are inside a loop, i would only worry about displaying the correct answer for the index am currently on, instead of passing the whole array into the correctanswer method.

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to make comments, and therefore would only give my suggestions here. First of, due to client or user mistrust, I bet you are using some kind of backend api for the marking. That is, you send api request each time the submit button is clicked. So now here is where you would integrate with what you are trying to achieve, upon hitting the backend, the json response will have the questions plus the correctly selected answers and now in your loop you can show the div's  ( correct and incorrect ) based on the correctness of the answer provided.

Steps:

- Show the questions
- Mark the questions (backend)
- Show the questions now with answer status (wrong or correct)
- Show the correct or error block based on the answer status